# Can't apply Theme from Android Action Bar Style Generator

Tags: android, android-layout

I finished [Android Action Bar Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) and downloaded the zip from there.
I copied and pasted all the folder in res, then changed the theme to let my app use the theme I edited. but The result is nothing changed!!!!

I am still beginner here. I am still not sure if there are other thing to deal with about changing Theme.

**style_example.xml** in folder values (created by the [generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/))

```
<style name="Theme.Example" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example</item>
    <item name="actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Example</item>
    <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Example</item>
    <item name="actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_example</item>
    <item name="actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Example</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Example.Widget</item>

</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Solid.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_example</item>
    <item name="backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar">
    <item name="background">@drawable/ab_transparent_example</item>
    <item name="progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Example</item>
</style>

<style name="PopupMenu.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.PopupMenu"> 
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>   
</style>

<style name="DropDownListView.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionBar.TabView">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
</style>

<style name="DropDownNav.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.DropDown.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_example</item>
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_example</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ProgressBar.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
    <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_example</item>
</style>

<style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Example" parent="@style/Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton.CloseMode">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_example</item>
</style>

<!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
<style name="Theme.Example.Widget" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat">
    <item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Example</item>
    <item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Example</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml** (I just forgot to change the name so it is "Theme.Example")

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.mes.learnupdater1" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" > --------------------- Theme applied
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".Main2Activity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main2" >
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want customized your them you need to edit theme under the value folder style. XML file

Comment: for better understand, I edited the question and uploaded the style xml. the [Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/) give us the style_example.xml for us already.

Comment: android:theme="@style/Theme.Example" > ------- Replaced style to style_example

Comment: You meant android:theme="@style_example/Theme.Example" ? I tried Gazi, @style_example/ is the unknown resource.

Comment: if it show unknown resource then style_example id is not create in R.Java file ...................if style_example.xml and style.xml theme name is same name then change style_example.xml theme name and copy the theme into style.xml and put the theme name  android:theme="@style/ them name that you customized "

Comment: I tried sorry, I couldn't. Anyway I jsut found that in the page it said "Deprecated" maybe unusable for now. Thanks for your trying Gazi, you did your best.